# Rect.GetWorldCorners(Vector3[]) does not return correct values when the RectTransform is managed by a LayoutGroup

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I'm using the function Rect.GetWorldCorners(Vector3[]) to get the array of corners of a Rect in world space.

This works fine when the Rect is not managed by a layout group (i.e., Grid Layout Group, Vertical Layout Group, etc...).

When I add a layout group, the function returns an array of vectors all with X and Y set to zero, and I'm trying to figure out why.

Code Sample:

```
Vector3[] rectCorners = new Vector3[4];

// then we get the rect transform components of the button
RectTransform selectableRect = selectable.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

// then we get their edges points. This works fine when the Rect is not managed by a grid layout group or similar.
selectableRect.GetWorldCorners(rectCorners);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's actually working, I just had to delay my script to allow the Layout Group to initialize.